# Right way to check for key in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

So have been wondering. Let d be a dictionary...What is the right (more pythonic) way to check whether key is in dictionary:

```
k in d
  or
k in d.keys()
```

or something else??

Comment: Either one is fine. I usually do the first.

Comment: @Cyber: **No**, not in Python 2 it isn't.

Comment: `k in d` is the way to go

Comment: Or you can use d[k] directly and catch the exception (if missing key is rare) or d.get(k,default) for value in case of non-existence. Then you never need to make the check.

Comment: you can also use `dict.get(<key>)`. It returns `None` if the key is not present

Comment: When you're asking "which is more pythonic", think about the language design. Remember that "there should be one obvious way to do it". Why would a dict act like a container (and, in fact, an iterable) of keys if the language designers didn't want `k in d` (and `for k in in d:` and similar) to be that one obvious way? (Sometimes the answer will be "historical reasons that no longer make sense", but usually not…)

Comment: The problem with `d.get(k)` is that when `d[k] = None` then `k in d != (d.get(k) is not None)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Always use

```
k in d
```

This is an O(1) constant time operation.

The alternative, `k in d.keys()`, is a O(N) linear time operation in Python 2, and at best an unnecessary method call in Python 3. Don't use it.

`d.keys()` is 3 extra steps, an attribute lookup, and a function call, and the creation of a new object. In Python 2 that is a list object of all the keys (requiring listing those keys first), in Python 3 it is a dictionary view. Both are *entirely redundant* when just testing for the presence of a key. And in Python 2, the containment test against the list object requires a scan of all the elements until a match is found.

Answer (score 3):

`k in d` is definitely the best way to proceed with as it will be much faster O(1) since it will use the dictionary's hashing as compared to doing a linear search, which would be the case when you will be calling keys would do.

There is one more alternative to use `dict.has_key(key)`. ALthough  "has_key" is deprecated in Python 3.0+

Comment: `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated. It requires an attribute lookup and a function call (2 instructions), vs. one bytecode instruction for the membership test with `in`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:- Yes I have updated that!

Comment: It is deprecated in Python 2, *removed altogether* in Python 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:- Indeed!

Answer (score 2):

### Comparison

For the record, a comparison (thanks to `timeit` module) with a try/except too.

### Code

```
# Comparison of checking if key is in a dict

lend = 200
idx = 200-1 

d = {}  
for i in range(lend):
    d[i]=i*2

def ktry(): 
    try:    
        d[idx]  
        # return True if d[idx] else True
        # return True
    except KeyError:
        return False
    else:   
        return True

def kind(): 
    return idx in d

def kindkeys():
    return idx in d.keys()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("kind()", setup="from __main__ import kind"))         
    print(timeit.timeit("ktry()", setup="from __main__ import ktry")) 
    print(timeit.timeit("kindkeys()", setup="from __main__ import kindkeys"))
```

### Results

Here are some timing results (in seconds) for different dict length and key in or not in dict:

Short dict:

```
lend = 200
idx = 0

>> 0.18031001091   # k in d
>> 0.216886997223  # try/except
>> 1.06729197502   # k in d.keys()
```

Out of short dict:

```
lend = 200
idx = 201

>> 0.178912878036  # k in d
>> 1.32136297226   # try/except
>> 4.93310189247   # k in d.keys()
```

Long dict:

```
lend = 20000
idx = 1

>> 0.178980827332  # k in d
>> 0.22277712822   # try/except
>> 105.207716942   # k in d.keys()
```

Out of long dict:

```
lend = 20000
idx = 20001

>> 0.184767007828  # k in d
>> 1.38200902939   # try/except
>> 490.606647968   # k in d.keys()
```

### Conclusion

When the key is in dict, the try/except method is a bit slower than `k in d`. However, if the key is not in dict the try/except performs poorly but better than `k in d.keys()`.

Given performance and readability, `k in d` has to be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

k in d is efficient. When you do d.keys() you are getting all the keys as a list and then checking inside the list. So it has to form a list first and depending on the list size peformance will be slower. There are better ways to check time taken but this should help you see the difference:

```
d={}
for i in range(1000000):
    d[i]=i*2

start_time = time.time()
if 2 in d:
    print "yes"
print("-key in d -- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
if 2 in d.keys():
    print "yes"
print("--key in d.keys()- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output on my Pc:

```
yes
-key in d -- 0.0 seconds ---
yes
--key in d.keys()- 0.0169999599457 seconds ---
```

Comment: if you are going to time code use timeit

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out in Python 3 for curiosity, indeed both look like an O(1) operations now in contrast to Python 2.

```
import random
import string

def rand_string(length):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    return ''.join(random.choice(
            string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                   for i in range(length)
            )

big_dict = {rand_string(20):rand_string(20) for i in range(10000)}
```

```
%timeit 10 in big_dict
%timeit 'M99FvcvRTcnl782Hlv2S' in big_dict

10000000 loops, best of 3: 62.2 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 60.4 ns per loop

%timeit 10 in big_dict.keys()
%timeit 'M99FvcvRTcnl782Hlv2S' in big_dict.keys()

10000000 loops, best of 3: 140 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 140 ns per loop
```